# overlapping lines not rendering correctly

Tags: wpf, user-interface, canvas, rendering

I'm rendering a bunch of lines in wpf on a canvas. Some of them overlap and I would like this to appear as one solid line. This does not seem to be the case.

I created a demo app to reproduce the issue (code below). In this demoapp I could set Snapdevicepixels=true on the canvas and the rendering became correct.

However in my real application, this does not seem to fix the problem.

- I doublechecked that the snaptodevicepixel was set to true via Snoop
- I tried setting snaptodevicepixels=true on the root visual entity in visual tree inside snoop but that also did not fix the issue.

What else could cause this visual problem?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var lines = GetLines(i*50 + 51.3367948717949d);
            foreach (var polyline in lines)
            {
                myCanvas.Children.Add(polyline);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Polyline> GetLines(double x)
    {
        var line1 = GetLine();
        line1.Points.Add(new Point(x: x + 1 / 3, y: 100));
        line1.Points.Add(new Point(x: x + 1 / 3, y: 50));

        var line2 = GetLine();
        line2.Points.Add(new Point(x: x + 1 / 3, y: 95));
        line2.Points.Add(new Point(x: x + 1 / 3, y: 100));
        line2.Points.Add(new Point(x: x+50 + 1 / 3, y: 100));
        return new List<Polyline>() {line1,line2};
    }

    public Polyline GetLine()
    {
        var result=  new Polyline();
        result.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        result.StrokeThickness = 2;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you set it on the Window as well?

Comment: Hi d.moncada. I tried setting the snaptodevicepixels in xaml on the mainwindow (earlier I already did this during runtime in snoop) and verified through snoop that this property was inherited in all child controls, but still the problem remains. Next thing I tried was to make sure all my x values (decimal) were rounded down with Math.Floor() but this also had no success.